# Welches Zeichen verwenden Schweizer als Dezimaltrennzeichen, wenn es nicht um Währungsangaben geht?

Tags: numbers, swiss-standard-german

Bezüglich Währungen scheint die Schweiz eindeutig mit Dezimalpunkten zu arbeiten. Siehe [Wikipedia-Artikel zum Dezimaltrennzeichen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dezimaltrennzeichen).

Aber bezüglich normaler Zahlen, wie Entfernungsangaben bekomme ich widersprüchliche Informationen.

Auf [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123920/why-differs-german-and-swiss-number-to-string-conversion) habe ich die gleiche Frage bezüglich der von Microsoft Windows verwendeten Ländereinstellung gestellt. Sowohl Windows wie auch IBM verwenden den Punkt als Dezimaltrennzeichen in der Schweizer Ländereinstellung. Es dürfte praktisch schon einige Anstrengungen erfordern, die Schreibweisungen umzusetzen.

Comment: Impliziert `normale` Zahlen, dass Zahlen im Kontext der Währung ihr Wesen ändern, und `anormal` werden?

Comment: Ich denke, das im Alltag bei Währung eigentlich keine Dezimalzahlen gebraucht werden, sondern hier Paare von ganzen Zahlen für Währungseinheit und Untereinheit verwendet werden.

Comment: Du meinst, ein Schweizer schreibt immer 14 Franken 30 Rappen (ist doch Rappen, oder?), und 7 € 20 ¢? Das wundert mich - ich war aber auch selten und nur kurz in der Schweiz, und lang ist es her. Hier https://www.nzz.ch/mynzz/bestellung/order_2.jsf?product=NZZ/INLAND kann man die NZZ für 548.00 abonnieren.

Comment: Besser noch: rechts die Börsenkurse: http://www.nzz.ch/finanzen

Comment: Oh, da hab ich sehr missverständlich ausgedrückt. Ich weiss, das der Währungsbetrag Fr. 14.30 oder 14.30 Franken geschrieben wird (siehe Schreibanweisungen). Was ich sagen wollte, ist das der Punkt hier nicht als klassisches Dezimaltrennzeichen verstanden wird.

Comment: Sondern als was? Als unklassisches?

Answer (score 7):

Jedenfalls für deutsch- und italienisch Texte sind die [Schreibweisungen der Bundeskanzlei](http://www.bk.admin.ch/dokumentation/sprachen/04915/05016/index.html?lang=de) bzw. die [Istruzioni della Cancelleria federale per la redazione dei testi ufficiali in italiano](http://www.bk.admin.ch/dokumentation/sprachen/04850/05005/index.html?lang=it) eindeutig: Tausendergruppen werden durch ein Leerzeichen voneinander abgetrennt, als Dezimaltrennzeichen fungiert grundsätzlich das Komma (auch bei Entfernungen, siehe die Beispiele zu Regeln 514 und 549), bei Geldbeträgen der Punkt. Im französischsprachigen Bereich dient (gemäß den «[Instructions sur la présentation des textes officiels en français](http://www.bk.admin.ch/dokumentation/sprachen/04908/04910/index.html?lang=fr)», Regel 44) ebenfalls das Komma generell als Dezimaltrennzeichen; für Währungsbeträge wird auch hier der Punkt verwendet, wie sich implizit aus dem ersten in der Regel 251 angeführten Beispiel ergibt. In allen diesen Quellen konnte ich prima vista keine Regel zu einer abweichenden Behandlung von Entfernungsangaben finden.

Comment: Ich habe mir gerade Abschnitt 264 in den Schreibweisungen der Bundeskanzlei angesehen. Kann man in der Schweiz nicht einfach Shift-ä drücken, um ein großes Ä zu erhalten. Kein Wunder das kaum jemand die Anweisungen beachtet. Faszinierend auch, wie oft dort Microsoft Word erwähnt wird, während gerade die Microsoft Produkte mit dazu betragen den Punkt als das Schweizer Dezimaltrennzeichen aufzufassen.

Comment: @bernd_k: Was das Ä betrifft: SHIFT+ä geht in der Tat nicht ohne weiteres, siehe die [Wikipedia zum Schweizer Tastaturlayout](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tastaturbelegung#Schweiz) (wusste ich aber bis eben gerade auch noch nicht...).

Comment: Kleine typographische Anmerkung: Die Grundregel lautet nicht Trennung mit Leerzeichen sondern Dreiergruppen bilden. Grund dieser Angabe dürfte eine typographische sein. Ziffern werden nicht mit Leerzeichen, sondern mit _Spatium_ getrennt. Siehe z.B. in [Mikrotypographie-Regeln](http://www.dante.de/tex/Dokumente/NeubauerII.pdf) Seite 3. Später führen die _ Schreibweisungen der Bundeskanzlei_ allerdings für Word das geschützte Leerzeichen auf (Soll Trennungen verhindern) - Vermutlich weil das Spatium für Word zu kompliziert ist.

Comment: @knut: Danke für den Hinweis - habe eben zudem [bei WP](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Spatien.jpg) gesehen, dass man Spatien sogar im 500er-Pack kaufen kann :-)

Comment: Die Frage ist nun, wer sich an diese Vorgaben hält. Behörden und Schulen tun es wohl. Wie sieht es mit den Medien aus? In der IT wird diese Vorgabe offenbar weitestgehend ignoriert.

Comment: Meinst Du die Spatien oder den Dezimaltrenner? Für den Trenner lässt sich das nur schwer beurteilen. Beispiele aus der NZZ für Geldbeträge mit Punkt als Trenner wurden ja schon gepostet; das scheint auch woanders (wahllose Beispiele: [Zeitschrift IT-Business](http://www.itbusiness.ch/index.php?n=nav2.htm&p=mediadaten/tarife.htm), [Swisscom-Onlineshop](http://shop.swisscom.ch/Onlineshop/Pages/Products/Products.aspx?cat=OS_Festnetz&subcat=OS_Telefone&drilldown=7&lang=DE&subsubcat=OS_Schnurlos)) Standard zu sein. Hotel-Webseiten nennen Zimmerpreise ebenfalls in dieser Form.

Comment: Nein Währung ist unproblematisch. Interessanter sind eher Laborwerte aus dem medizinischen Bereich. http://www.symptome.ch/vbboard/koennte-problem/69181-niedriger-hb-wert-ursachen.html z.B verwendet Komma als Dezimaltrennzeichen, aber das ist der populäre Bereich, und sagt nichts über den medizinischen Alltag in den Labors der Krankenhäuser.