# How to say decimal numbers in Swiss German?

Tags: swiss-german

For example how to say 3.5 (three **point** five)? Is it like Deutsch drei **komma** fünf?

Comment: for how to write "swiss" numbers take a look at [Welches Zeichen verwenden Schweizer als Dezimaltrennzeichen, wenn es nicht um Währungsangaben geht?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/welches-zeichen-verwenden-schweizer-als-dezimaltrennzeichen-wenn-es-nicht-um-wä)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Swiss people will always say a "**Komma**" when it comes to exact decimal numbers. Just with the relevant dialect.

**2.3** can be "**zwoi komma drüü**" or "**zwei komma drei**" (or similar) depending on where you are. But the "Komma" never changes

You can either write a comma or a point. Comma is what is usually taught in schools whereas point is often used in print or computers.

One thing to note: for the .5 decimal it's very common to use "**ehalb**" (ein halbes) if you're talking about it in a non-scientific context. (Prices, hours etc).

1.5 is also special as it can be either "**einehalb**" or "**anderthalb**".

Anything else is again used regularily (your example of 3.5 is "**dreiehalb**" or "**drüüehalb**")

Comment: nice explained!! if there are several digits after the decimal point, the numbers are listed separately as in english. EXAMPLE: 23.375 we say "**drei-und-zwanzig** Komma **drei sieben fünf**“.